# jquery check radio button with certain value

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I think, I make a simple mistake here:

```
$('.myRadioButtons').val('3121').attr("checked",true);
```

But this one does not work too:

```
$(':input[value="3121"]').attr("checked",true);
```

The same problem also with "prop" instead of "attr".

Thank you..

EDIT: Here is online: http://jsfiddle.net/WWC4G/1/

Comment: Seems to work for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/KUbHY/ (and you should use prop)

Comment: @adeneo: here is online (http://jsfiddle.net/WWC4G/1/): there are also other radio buttons with the same value but different css classes -> therefore find the right class & right value and check it

Comment: @user2819288 - `$('.myclass :input[value="3121"]')` looks for an input element **INSIDE .myclass** with that value, it should be `$('.myclass[value="3121"]')`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WWC4G/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using below

```
$('input[value="3121"]').prop("checked",true)

  or

$('input[value="3121"]').attr("checked","checked")
```

Comment: OP already tried `.prop()` it not working for him .Read the question

Comment: How would setting the value return a string and not the jQuery object ?

Comment: there are also other radio buttons with the same value but different css classes -> therefore find the right class and check it..